# in OS X, what is the BASE graphics drawing layer?

Tags: macos, opengl, graphics, drawing, appkit

I am beginning GUI development in OSX, and I am wondering, what is the VERY BASE layer in the system for which to draw graphics? It seems as if there are so many upper level abstractions (AppKit, OpenGL, CG, etc), which are nice and timesaving, but for me unusable until I understand the base layer (unless its binary or assembly, in which case I throw in the towel).

Comment: What makes these other interfaces unusable?

Comment: there not, I just wouldn't feel comfortable enough, because I'm paranoid about stuff like that

Comment: @roozbubu: Then that sounds like a problem you need to get over *now*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am beginning GUI development in OSX, and I am wondering, what is the VERY BASE layer in the system for which to draw graphics?

Believe it or not, but ever since MacOS X Tiger the whole graphics stack it based on OpenGL. Below OpenGL is only the GPU driver and then the bare metal.

> It seems as if there are so many upper level abstractions (AppKit, OpenGL, CG, etc), which are nice and timesaving, but for me unusable until I understand the base layer (unless its binary or assembly, in which case I throw in the towel).

Why are they unusable for you? What do you expect to gain from the added knowledge? The lower the level is, that you're using, the more intimate you must be with how it works to make efficient use of it. OpenGL itself is already fairly low level. The OpenGL implementation hides some gory details from you, like on demand texture data swapping from fast to regular memory and the likes, and the GLSL compiler is also rather high level. But on the other side to use OpenGL efficiently you should deliver data in the format the GPU natively works with, shaders can be cached in their binary form and buffer objects provide you with a API for DMA transfers.

If you were really interested in the lowest layer, that you'd have to look at the GPU design, i.e. the metal. AMD did actually publish full programming documentation on some of their GPUs (Google for OpenGPU).

Answer (score 0):

You could do a lot worse than have a look at the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1). It's the layer you will be using most often and understanding this will form the basis for any further investigation you do.